# Podio API : How to get a file id given an item id

Tags: podio

Here's a Podio API question ...

How do you get the file id that's associated with an item (given that I know the item id). I cannot find that on the API documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the item: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360 and read the 'files' key from the response. That will give you a list of the files ids.